# PrincipalPermissionMode | How does different options work

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Relating to various modes of principlePermissionMode attribute of `<serviceAuthorization>` element, few queries below -

1. Can you provide/point me to an example how PrincipalPermission can be used when its mode is selected as "Custom" in configuration?
2. What is the significance of "None" and "Always" modes? With "None", does it mean Thread.CurrentPrincipal will be empty?
3. With "UseAspNetRoles" mode, my understanding is, the authorization happens with `<roleProvider>` selected in the config and the "Name" and "Roles" field values of PrincipalPermissionMode are validated against it. If the clientCredentialType is certificate, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows how it gets validated. Does the settings in `<roleProvider>` do not play any role here? Since UseAspNetRoles mode is used, it has check the `<roleProvider>` to get the source against which the roles is to be checked. How does certificate credential type relates to `<roleProvider>` in this case and what should be the setting required in `<roleProvider>` for this credential type?

Thanks!